# SSH hangs indefinitely after a while using Ethernet cable; can't even disconnect

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ethernet

I'm having a strange issue where SSH stops responding completely after a while ranging from between a couple of minutes to half an hour. But only with Ethernet; with Wi-Fi there are no problems.

When it stops responding, I can't even disconnect with `Ctrl+D`; I have to use `<Enter>~.`.

When I use SFTP in any GUI application (e.g. FileZilla, IntelliJ, DBeaver) that's not a terminal, the applications never handle the same stopping of responding; the connection always stays pending, and I can't stop the connection by pressing Cancel, and find I have no choice but to exit and restart the application.

This happens to ~10 completely different SSH servers, not just one.

I have tried two things:

1. I've tried using TCPKeepAlive. Here is my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    ServerAliveInterval 100
```

Here is one of the server's `~/.ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 100
```

I'm pretty sure it's not a keep alive issue, because for one I have it configured to not happen, and second is that the symptom of not being kept alive is to disconnect, but disconnecting does not happen; it just hangs forever, and you can't even cancel the connection. Another reason is that the hanging starts randomly and is not tied to activity at all; I might run one command successfully, but once I would start running the next command shortly afterwards, it would stop responding.

2. Another thing I tried: running SSH with full verbosity: `-vvv`. Unfortunately, though it shows all sorts of debug messages, when the connection stops responding, it does not output anything at all. It just stops responding. I don't have the output here at the moment, but I can provide it if needed, though it won't be helpful.
3. `ssh -o IPQoS=0 <server>`
4. Proxying `ns` like in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/401569/176014

I am using Ubuntu 19.10.